# How to specify preprocessor includes in Bazel? (-include common_header.h)

Tags: c++, bazel

I am trying to use code in Bazel, which uses the `-include` flag (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) to always include a config header.
The config header sets a number of #defines that are required by the header files, ie enabling/disabling certain APIs.

The config header looks something like this:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H_
#define CONFIG_H_

// part of library, defines some stuff to use in this file
#include "config_defs.h"

<#define several config settings>

// also part of library, has a defaults via `#ifndef`->`#define`
#include "config_defaults.h" 

#endif  // CONFIG_H_
```

Unfortunately, adding that header to every file is not an option.
I would like to avoid having to convert the complete config and all defaults to `-D` (ie via `defines = [...]`), due to the number of settings.

From the looks of it, the config would need to end up in `CcToolchainConfigInfo.includes` (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html#cctoolchainconfiginfo-build-variables), but I didn't figure out how to get it there.

I tried to do add the `-include` in a toolchain (via feature flags), but couldn't figure out how to tell it to mount the file.

Comment: I managed to integrate it by making a custom toolchain (with `-include` in feature flags) and adding it to the relevant filegroups in `cc_toolchain`. Still far from optimal, but works...

Comment: Found another way - I am now using a `genrule` to include the config header at the beginning of each .h/.c file.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Add --define to .bazelrc:

```
build --define VAR1=hello
build --define VAR2=world
```

2. Define a macro which will wrap default cc_library:

```py
def my_cc_library(
  name,
  copts=[],
  **kwargs):

  cc_library(
    name = name,
    copts = copts + ["-DVAR=1"],
    **kwargs)
```

I recommend second option.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that because the header config also includes a file (`config_defaults.h`) with large number of default values (some dependent on other values), which i would have to manually add in this case, bloating my BUILD files.

Comment: @AcuteDrops there will be no bload if you use `my_cc_library` instead of cc_library in BUILD files. Define your values once in this macro.

Comment: As i mentioned previously, the `config_defaults.h` contains a whole lot of defaults, most of which I do not want to touch... I would have to convert all defaults from that file (which the library provides) to a massive `defines` list/dict (what I meant by bloat, doesn't matter if its hidden in some other file) and merge the few changes i want into it.

Comment: @AcuteDrops What compiler do you use? Pass this flag: -include "config_defaults.h" if you use gcc. There're similar flags for other compilers.

Comment: My problem, as stated in the original question, is how to cleanly include files via `-include`.
And if I am including a header anyway, I might as well include my own and put my defines in there.