# how to include header file for each file compiled via bazel

Tags: c++, c, bazel

I have a project that I'm building using bazel. My application references another bazel repository as a dependency, in its BUILD file, let's call this @dep. I cannot make any changes to the code in @dep, but I need to override a C macro defined in one of the header files in @dep.

I thought about using the compiler option -D to define the symbol defined at the top of the header file I want to replace, which contains the C macro, and then using -include to include a different header file with my macro, for all files in @dep which are being compiled via bazel. But in cc_binary, there is no option for -include, and copt = [] will only work for the target being compiled and not for its dependencies.

I came across this post but unfortunately the solution was not posted - [How to specify preprocessor includes in Bazel? (-include common_header.h)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67719737/how-to-specify-preprocessor-includes-in-bazel-include-common-header-h)

Comment: I'm thinking a `feature` could do the job, maybe you can figure out the details yourself: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html#features

Comment: @Andreas it seems that that would require me to define a new toolchain, that seems overkill for something as simple as what I need? The documentation is also very hard to understand. I don’t get why they don’t provide a way to use -include on the compiler command line for each file compiled, via the cc_binary build rule. They have defines = [] after all.

Comment: Dear OP, is this for C or C++ ?

Comment: @user426 C++ but I don’t think that matters much.

Answer (score 0):

> I don’t get why they don’t provide a way to use -include on the compiler command line for each file compiled, via the cc_binary build rule. They have defines = [] after all.

In general bazel doesn't provide a lot of mechanisms like that because it can cause scaling issues in large repositories. E.g. say project1 and project2 depend on the same tree of 1000 cc_library targets. Building both of them together results in 1000 cc_library targets being built. But if cc_binary had a way to change the way its dependencies are compiled, and project2 did something like that, then building the two projects together now requires building 2000 cc_library targets, which doubles memory requirements, remote caching requirements, remote execution requirements, increases analysis time.

For the `defines` attribute, that affects things that depend on the target with `defines`, but doesn't affect the dependencies of that target (it goes "up" the build graph, instead of "down", if cc_binary is at the top).

That said, there are ways to change the way dependencies of a target are compiled, these are called "configuration transitions". (e.g. android_binary uses one to compile multiple cpu architectures in a single app, but going from [x86] to [x86, arm64] ~doubles as above). Configuration transitions are little involved though.

There are easier options like `--copt` on the command line, which affect the entire build, which might work. The below example might do what you need. It relies on the macro being surrounded by "#ifndef". It doesn't seem to work without the #ifndef, some cursory searching says macros in source code can't be replaced on the command line (not a c/c++ expert myself). If overriding the macro really requires it being in a source file, that's tricky because there's no straight forward way to add a file to the inputs of every cc action (or some subset). If it does work, you can add  `build --copt=...` to a `.bazelrc` file at the root of your workspace so you don't have to add it to the command line. Otherwise, the only other thing I can think of is a custom toolchain, as others have mentioned.

```
repo1$ bazel run foo
INFO: Analyzed target //:foo (1 packages loaded, 160 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:foo up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/foo
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.318s, Critical Path: 0.09s
INFO: 5 processes: 1 internal, 4 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
bar is 16

repo1$ bazel run foo --copt=-DBAZ=15
INFO: Build option --copt has changed, discarding analysis cache.
INFO: Analyzed target //:foo (0 packages loaded, 160 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:foo up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/foo
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.252s, Critical Path: 0.09s
INFO: 5 processes: 1 internal, 4 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
bar is 38
```

`repo1/BUILD`:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "foo",
  srcs = ["foo.c", "foo.h"],
  deps = ["@repo2//:bar"],
)
```

`repo1/WORKSPACE`:

```
local_repository(
  name = "repo2",
  path = "../repo2",
)
```

`repo1/foo.c`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
  printf("bar is %d\n", bar());
  return 0;
}
```

`repo1/foo.h`:

`repo2/BUILD`:

```
cc_library(
  name = "bar",
  srcs = ["bar.c"],
  hdrs = ["bar.h"],
  deps = [":baz"],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
  name = "baz",
  srcs = ["baz.c"],
  hdrs = ["baz.h"],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

`repo2/WORKSPACE`:

`repo2/bar.c`:

```
#include "bar.h"
#include "baz.h"

int bar() {
  return baz() + BAR;
}
```

`repo2/bar.h`:

```
#define BAR 8

int bar();
```

`repo2/baz.c`:

```
#include "baz.h"

int baz() {
  return BAZ * 2;
}
```

`repo2/baz.h`:

```
#ifndef BAZ
#define BAZ 4
#endif

int baz();
```